# How to encode "structure contains one or more X" in a .yaml file

Tags: yaml, openapi

I'm trying to define an OpenAPI interface in a .yaml file.
The interface specification says that one of the parameters will be a data structure `foo` containing, among other things, one or more members of a second data structure `bar`. In C++ I would define a structure containing a vector of `bar` but I cannot figure out how to encode this in YAML. I tried making a list with just one item, and Swagger Editor complained:

```
# ... details omitted

- in: header
  name: foo
  required: true
  schema:
    type: object
    properties:
      identity:
        type: integer
      version:
        type: integer
      - bar: # <<<<< bad indentation of a mapping entry
        type: object
        properties:
          key:
            type: string
          value:
            type: string
```

This doesn't look like it's really an indentation problem. I say this because the only level of indentation that removes the error is back out level with the `in`. Note that, if I remove the dash and following space, the editor shows no errors, so I'm pretty sure there are no other issues here.

**main question** How can I define this parameter as something containing *one or more* structures of type `bar`?

**bonus question** Is there a way to name the structures I'm defining, e.g. `KeyValuePair` for `bar`?

Comment: Mind that OpenAPI is just one of many applications of YAML. If you use YAML for a specific purpose, as is the case here, tagging that purpose helps your question to be visible to relevant users. I added the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This doesn't look like it's really an indentation problem.

No, but it *is* a syntactic error that has nothing to do with OpenAPI (or JSON Schema, which is what is most relevant for your problem). YAML defines the structure of your document, and you have made a structural error.
This snippet is enough to see the error:

```yaml
      version:
        type: integer
      - bar:
```

The key `version:` shows that we are inside a *mapping* here, i.e. a list of key-value pairs. What follows is a nested mapping with the single entry `type: integer`. Then however, a `-` follows on the indentation level of `version:`. In YAML, this is a sequence indicator. But there is no *sequence* at the indentation level of `version:`; instead, this indentation level holds a *mapping*. You cannot have a sequence item as part of a mapping, since a mapping contains key-value pairs. The error message could of course be a better one.

Now what you actually want to do is to define an array of bar (JSON term for a vector of bar):

```
      version:
        type: integer
      bar:
        type: array
        items:
          type: object
          properties:
            key:
              type: string
            value:
              type: string
```

Be aware of the important difference between the syntactic YAML structure of your input, and the desired semantic of your input. You want to describe an array in your JSON Schema, but that does not mean that you have to use a YAML sequence for that. You also don't write `42` if you want to define an integer-type field.

Also be aware that `bar` is the name of the field, not the name of the type. You can reference previously defined types with [$ref](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/using-ref/).

Comment: That makes it look easy. It's the thinking in the second paragraph that really eludes the newbie, I think. Thanks!